# What is the difference between shell options -v and -x for debugging?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging, sh, zsh

`-x` means xtrace and `-v` means verbose.

When researching, I find that `bash -x` "expands commands" while `-v` prints out the entire command to stdout before execution.

The only difference I see when testing this is that `bash -v <scriptname>` will display comments of each command as well.

Is this really the only difference? Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I have not voted. See: `help set | grep '^ *-[xv]'`

Answer (score 8):

From the manual:

> ```
>   -v  Print shell input lines as they are read.
>   -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
> ```

You can see this distinction when looking at how piped commands are handled:

```
$ set -v
$ echo "Hello World" | sed 's/World/Earth/'
echo "Hello World" | sed 's/World/Earth/'
Hello Earth
```

versus:

```
$ set -x
$ echo "Hello World" | sed 's/World/Earth/'
    + sed s/World/Earth/
    + echo 'Hello World'
    Hello Earth
```

Also, it appears that xtrace (-x) uses the $PS4 variable, while verbose (-v) does not.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs are very similar for simple commands, but it seems that `set -v` (verbose) simply repeats the input line, while `set -x` (xtrace) shows the command(s) that are run after variable expansions and word splitting, etc. Considering the examples below, it seems to me that it's worth using both when debugging shell scripts: *verbose* helps navigate the script and show the intention of the commands, while *xtrace* shows in more detail what is actually being run. I'm going to use `set -vx` when debugging scripts from now on. The differences become more obvious in examples with variables, command lists, functions, etc:

```bash
$ set +vx           # both disabled (default for most people)
$ foo=(1 2 '3 three')
$ printf 'foo is %s\n' "${foo[@]}" && echo ''
foo is 1
foo is 2
foo is 3 three

$ set -v            # verbose
$ printf 'foo is %s\n' "${foo[@]}" && echo ''
printf 'foo is %s\n' "${foo[@]}" && echo ''
foo is 1
foo is 2
foo is 3 three

$ set +v
set +v
$ set -x            # xtrace
$ printf 'foo is %s\n' "${foo[@]}" && echo ''
+ printf 'foo is %s\n' 1 2 '3 three'
foo is 1
foo is 2
foo is 3 three
+ echo ''

$ set +x
+ set +x
$ set -vx           # both verbose and xtrace
$ printf 'foo is %s\n' "${foo[@]}" && echo ''
printf 'foo is %s\n' "${foo[@]}" && echo ''  # from verbose, input line simply repeated
+ printf 'foo is %s\n' 1 2 '3 three'         # from xtrace, command list split, variables substituted
foo is 1
foo is 2
foo is 3 three
+ echo ''

# word splitting behaviour is made more obvious by xtrace
# (note the array is unquoted now)
$ printf 'foo is %s\n' ${foo[@]} && echo ''
printf 'foo is %s\n' ${foo[@]} && echo ''
+ printf 'foo is %s\n' 1 2 3 three           # missing single quotes due to word splitting
foo is 1
foo is 2
foo is 3
foo is three                                 # !
+ echo ''

# function with both verbose and xtrace set
$ function bar { printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"; }
function bar { printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"; }  # verbose repeats definition, nothing output by xtrace
$ bar
bar                                          # verbose repeats function call
+ bar                                        # xtrace shows commands run
+ printf '%s\n' 1 2 '3 three'
1
2
3 three
```

**Aside: other shells**

The above examples are from `bash`. In my testing, the output of posix `dash` for both options is very similar, although of course no arrays are possible in that shell. `zsh` expands the xtrace output slightly by prepending with a line number, but otherwise behaves very similarly (although here, its [different word splitting behaviour](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq03.html) is apparent):

```
$ zsh
% foo=(1 2 '3 three')
% set -vx
% printf 'foo is %s\n' ${foo[@]} && echo ''
printf 'foo is %s\n' ${foo[@]} && echo ''    # verbose repeats input command
+zsh:14> printf 'foo is %s\n' 1 2 '3 three'  # xtrace prints expanded command with line number
foo is 1
foo is 2
foo is 3 three
+zsh:14> echo ''
```